# How can I copy text and paste it to a login form (Google drive app) using batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, google-drive-api

My company are using Google Drive to sync data between countryside, through Windows based tablets, and it their different offices across country.We use about 45 hosts, running Windows 7, 8.1, and 10 to sync data with Google Drive, with the same account.The password cannot be provided to the users. Only the Administrator (me) must know the password to sign in.The problem is that, everyday some users has contacted me to enter the password, because they get sign in errors, and they can´t sync files.... or they found unable to connect message error. Thus, I´d like to create a bat command that copies a password (text) and paste it in a form of Google Drive.

Someone help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Keeping a secret and distributing it to everyone in plain text are orthogonal goals.

Comment: If your application is using google drive sdk as you have tagged. Why aren't you using a service account.   You should not be sharing login and password with people.